# How to check if IntegerCache.high was set?

Tags: java

How can I check during runtime that `java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high` was set to a certain value.

For example, lets say that I want to check that the program was executed with `-Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=10000`.

I can't use `System.getProperty` because apparently Java saves this property to "saved properties". In Java 19 Integer class the code reads the value with:

```
String integerCacheHighPropValue =
    VM.getSavedProperty("java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high");
```

But if I import `jdk.internal.misc.VM` I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class percolation.Main (in unnamed module @0x1e80bfe8) cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.VM (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module @0x1e80bfe8
    at percolation.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Comment: I tried "--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED" and still got the same error (added it to the question). I'll try RuntimeMXBean next.

Comment: **1.** `--add-exports` also needed for compiling; **2.** virtual machine options (`-D`, `--add-exports`) must come BEFORE the class name when executing `java` (anything after the class name is passed as ARGUMENT to `main` method of your code)

Comment: Oh, you are right... between all the things I tried I apparently mixup up the order... now it works indeed... thanks!